# How to use addClause() outside setup() in Laravel Backpack?

Tags: laravel-backpack

Say we have the `UserCrudController` like so:

```
public function setup()
{
    // ...
    // This works:
    $this->crud->addClause('active');
    // ...
}
```

The `addClause()` works fine. Now say we add it outside the `setup()`:

```
public function posts()
{
    // ...
    // This DOES NOT work:
    $this->crud->addClause('active');
    // ...
}
```

Calling `addClause()` outside like this works, but if its inside a logic, it does not:

```
public function setup()
{
    // This works:
    $this->applyQueries();
}

private function applyQueries()
{
    // This works:
    $this->crud->addClause('active');

    // This DOES NOT work:
    if (true)
        $this->crud->addClause('active');
}
```

Recap: I need to call `addClause()` from another function and inside a logic. How?

Answer (score 0):

If you're creating a custom method, there's no way for Backpack to know what you want to do inside that method. Only what you write inside it will happen, in addition to what's in `setup()`, which is called in the `__constructor()`.

Depending on your use case (list/create/edit/preview/etc), I recommend you take a look at the logic inside Backpack's `CrudController`. The methods there contain the logic for the operations above, and do use the `addClause()`. Copy-paste whatever you need to your `posts()` method. You'll basically be able to use the query where the clauses have been added by taking advantage of the `$this->crud` object, so the query would be `$this->crud->query`.

Comment: This case is a little weird at the moment. Still looking into it. Thanks.

Comment: Could you see if a simple logic like this works?
`
if(\Route::currentRouteName()=='example'){
    $this->crud->addClause('active');
}
`